# Including file in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, include

I'm getting mad. I can't understand what's the problem.
[image: screenshot]
Obviously i'm trying a require_once() but it doesn't work. As you can see, the file should be in the right place. Anyone have a clue why it doesn't work?

Comment: Which OS you are using? May be there is permission or owner issues. If any of below answer solves your issue please mark them to "green".

Comment: it's a question from 2011. Probably that laptop has been recycled 2 or 3 times by now

Answer (score 7):

If you have a file in your vendors folder (i.e., vendors/filename.php)

You can do:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'filename');
```

Here's some more [examples](http://book.cakephp.org/view/944/Vendor-examples) of including vendors

Comment: i did that too, but it doesn't work either. The file is in a subfolder but i did a trick suggested on a few forum but didn't worked. Anyway now i got an idea.

Comment: It doesn't work because i work on a modified version of cakephp. Import doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Chobeat if the file's in a sub directory you just need to do `App::import('Vendor', 'path/to/filename');`

Comment: Do you know how to do if we want call vendor class in an extern class (in webroot path) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can include files in different ways:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

In your case you're using Lucene as a **vendor**, so the correct include would be:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'lucene/Search/Lucene');
```

to load /app/Vendor/lucene/Search/Lucene.php

Answer (score 1):

Just place your path appropiately. For instance

require_once('/cake/importedfolder/imported_file.php');

In as much as your .htaccess is set to have permission and mod_rewriting is enabled.

To narrate better: you can place the file or folder containing the file you want to import in the 'webroot' folder
 For instance we want to require a connection.php file (just to explain tho).
All you have to do is place the file in 'webroot'
And then require it. : thus 'require_once(/cake/connection.php');

Let me know if this helps.....